# Pick a specific level in the contour plot on matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAHTa.png) that I generated as a test of figuring out how contour plots work on matlab in general. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way I can plot just one of the lines but not necessarily the first line.

They way Matlab explains it is if you do:

```
 contour(X,Y,Z,1);
```

it will plot one of the lines but it's always the first one, but for my particular case I want the 3rd or 4th one. Is there a way to do that in Matlab?

Comment: What do you mean by "the first line"? If you want to plot the contour at a particular value you have to use a two element vector with the desired value twice:
`v = [2 2]; contour(X,Y,Z,v)`
Will plot the contour at value 2

Answer (score 5):

`contour(Z,N)` and `contour(X,Y,Z,N)` draw `N` contour lines, choosing the levels automatically. This is **not** what you want!

`contour(Z,V)` and `contour(X,Y,Z,V)` draw a contour line for each level specified in vector `V`.  Use `contour(Z,[v v])` or `contour(X,Y,Z,[v v])` to draw contours for the single level `v`.

Suggesting the levels of the 3rd and 4th line are `7` and `8` you have to write `contour(X,Y,Z,[7 7])` to only plot the 3rd line or `contour(X,Y,Z,[7 8])` to plot the 3rd and the 4th line.